# PHP cURL to Login and Post or Update status in Facebook without using API or SDK

Tags: php, facebook, curl

Is there a way to  Login and Post or Update status in Facebook with just PHP cURL? Just plain old form submission without api or sdk?

Comment: No, if it is possible without sdk and api, how are you suppose Facebook would know you are authenticated to do such actions?

Comment: I somehow found a code that log ins the account with php curl with form submission. I think it's possible to do with post/status updates.

Comment: What is the purpose of this? It's probably possible, although it would take some time to get it done. I'm pretty sure they have protection regarding such logins.

Comment: @tftd I got a code that works to login the account using curl but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to post.

Comment: You are not supposed to try and do that in the first place. If you want to interact with Facebook from the outside, then use their API.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but you'd essentially be rebuilding the core of the [Facebook PHP SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/5.0.0).
The minimum you'd need is to build is an OAuth 2.0 login flow, which - if you want to implement your own - is documented [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow). This is needed to obtain an access token that you can then use to make Graph API calls (every Graph API call requires an access token).

Making graph API calls is fairly easy to do with cURL, so you could do the same in PHP. To see example cURL commands, you can see the each Graph API endpoint's reference documentation [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference)